# ¿Como evitar el desplazamiento del ScrollView hasta el ultimo elemento en Android?

Tags: android, recyclerview, constraint-layout

Estoy usando `ScrollView` para una vista con múltiples elementos(`CardView`,`TextView`,`RecyclerView`), el problema que surge es cuando se carga la vista se desplaza hasta el ultimo elemento que es el `RecyclerView` y no desde el inicio de la Vista.

Estructura **vista.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView...>

        <TextView...>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView...>

        <TextView...>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView...>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

¿Como podría solucionar el desplazamiento de la vista ?

Comment: ¿ Tienes definido en el último elemento la propiedad focusable ="true" ?

Comment: Hola, @Elenasys no le asigne esa propiedad

Comment: Ok entonces define en el layout contenedor:  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: @Elenasys lo tengo definido en el CardView del diseño del RecyclerView, para agregar efecto de ondulación, pero ya he agregado la propiedad que indicas en la respuesta y funciona correcamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

con esto evitas que realice Scroll hacia el último elemento

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >
```

> `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`  Define la relación entre ViewGroup y sus descendientes cuando se busca
>   una vista para enfocar, en este caso evita el enfoque de alguno de sus
>   hijos.